# Unable to unistall mysql installer

Tags: mysql

I had some issues while installing MySQL the first time and it threw up some errors. When I tried to uninstall and reinstall I am unable to uninstall the MySQL Installer. Is there anything I can do to rectify this? 
OS : Windows 7 (32 BIT)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a *bit* too late, but I've encountered the same problem, so I hope it could help others.

Steps:

1. Find the version of installed MySQL installer (I could not find specific version, so I used the installation date and downloaded the corresponding version in MySQL archived downloads page) and download it.
2. Run it and choose to uninstall all the components. The installer itself will still be installed.
3. Right click on the downloaded installation file (i.e. mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.17.0.msi) and choose "Uninstall".

Answer (score 0):

did you try to uninstall MySQL Installer in Safe Mode?

If you don't know how to boot in Safe Mode follow these steps :

1- Start your computer
2- Press on the F8 key during all the time on booting
3- Safe Mode menu will appear and chose Safe Mode...

Then, go in your Control panel of windows and try to uninstall MySQL.

I think the problem is because MySQL is starting automatically when you log into windows. So, MySQL service is always running and when a service is running you can't uninstall it..

Hope it's help,

Dave

Comment: I tried that. It gave me a message saying that the installation may not have been proper and that's why the uninstall isn't happening.

Comment: Ok try to uninstall with this tools CCleaner follow this : (http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/using-ccleaner/uninstalling-programs)

Comment: I tried the options to uninstall via CCleaner. Run uninstaller option gives me the same result as the removeing application using control panel option. The delete entry option tells me that it cannot delete an MSI installer

Comment: Ok ahah that's wierd ! Try this (http://superuser.com/questions/225826/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-completely-uninstall-mysql)